# Creating a view permanently underneath UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My issue is that i need to have a single view just below the `UINavigationBar` on screen at all times whilst navigating through a sign up journey. This is to display the current step in signing up. This needs to stay on screen at all times as the stages animate as they change so simply pushing a new view onto a `UINavigationController` isn't sufficient.

See an example of what i need to achieve below

[image: example]

I need to have the red item persist at all times even when a new view controller is pushed on

To try fix this I have created a custom `UINavigationController` in order to have a sticky view be present regardless of what view controller is showing.

I have created this code which suits my needs however doesnt feel like the correct option. Especially as I need to support iOS 10 and `additionalSafeAreaInsets` is not available

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    stickyView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: navigationBar.frame.maxY, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60)
    children.forEach { $0.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 60, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) }
}
```

What would be a good way to make sure that the view controllers frame starts below this header view? Or maybe an alternative approach?

There seems to be very little stuff on this topic from what i can see on stack overflow